# Declare required sub-commands with scopt

Tags: scala, command-line, scopt

I want to declare *required* sub-commands using `scopt` (or sth. similar but Scala based).

For example, I want to have the following synopsis (similar to `man git`, for example):

```
mycli [--version] [--help] <command> [<args>]
```

whereas `<command>` is *required* to be one the sub-commands, e.g., `subA` and `subB`. Something like the following:

```
private val parser = new OptionParser[Config]("mycli") {
  head(s"${BuildInfo.name} v${BuildInfo.version} is © 2014 by ${BuildInfo.organization}")
  help("help")       text("prints this usage text")
  version("version") text("FIXME”)
  cmd("command") required() action {(c, config) => c match {
    case "subA" => config.copy(mode = "subA") children(
      arg[String]("<files>...") unbounded() optional() action {(rs, config) => config.copy(files = config.files :+ rs) },
      opt[Unit]  ("with-optA")                         action {(_ , config) => config.copy(optA  = true)},
      opt[Unit]  ("with-optB")                         action {(_ , config) => config.copy(optB  = true)})
    case "subB" => //...
    case _      => // ERROR! 
  } }
}
```

Any hint?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure this is kind of tricky, it can lead to many levels of children options.

Here is my Config class:

```
case class Config(cmd:String="", subcmd:String="")
```

Here is my parser:

```
val parser = new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("MyCLI") {
  head("Foo")
  cmd("cmdA") action { (_, c) => c.copy(cmd = "cmdA")
  } children(
    cmd("subA1") action { (_, c) => c.copy(subcmd = "subA1")},
    cmd("subA2") action { (_, c) => c.copy(subcmd = "subA2")}
    )
  cmd("cmdB") action { (_, c) => c.copy(cmd = "cmdA")
  } children(
    cmd("subA1") action { (_, c) => c.copy(subcmd = "subA1")},
    cmd("subA2") action { (_, c) => c.copy(subcmd = "subA2")}
    )
  checkConfig { c => c match {
    case Config("", _) => failure("No command given.")
    case Config(_, "") => failure("Must Choose a subcommand.")
    case _ => success

  }}
}
```

I hope this helps. I would replace `Config.cmd` with a sealed trait and objects. I didn't do that so that this would be copyable.

Each Subcommand can have children of their own, with another command, options or args.

The call to `checkConfig` is very important otherwise if no commands are given the application will silently exit.

Comment: Hi Nicholas. Thanks for your help, but how to adapt `checkConfig` such that `MyCLI --version` or `MyCLI --help` does not result in an error? I have added `version(...)` and `help(...)` right after `head(...)`. Second, how to adapt the `showUsage` message, such that `sage: MyCLI [dump|move] ...` becomes `sage: MyCLI <dump|move> ...` cause these are required?